# NOOBS and Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, noobs

Is [NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) and Raspbian written in Java and if I install anyone of the above on an SD card, does it work on Windows XP, 32-bit processor without any hardware requirements?

I want experience with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: `if I install any one of above on SD card does it work on Windows Xp, 32 bit processor without any hardware requirements`

What do you mean? Are you talking about simulating a PI on a desktop machine?

Comment: Yes I want simulate on it

Comment: experience RPi in a simulator is like kissing girls in a Hazmat suit -- does not quite feel like it should. you'd better go and get one, since RPi is very cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `NOOBS` and `Raspbian` are written in `C`. It is definitely not `Java`.

If you want to use `Raspbian` on a Windwos machine you can use an emulator like [QEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU).

Here is a [How-To install](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/). And here is the [Download Homepage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/) of the Project. The `GPIO`s are not emulated. If you want to experiment with hardware output you need to use a real Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank You , I had know about NOOBS and RASPBIAN on NetBeans website it's said Java SE Embedded support to deploy, run, debug or profile Java SE applications on an embedded device, such as Raspberry PI, directly from the NetBeans IDE.So I am interesting about NOOBS and RASPBIAN. Thank You.